# Should I Dockerize Angular App or Host Static in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I have a Docker app and currently have no backend (planning to make one in Spring Boot so it will be separated as microservices). Now, after my research, i have 2 options, I could push the app directly into S3 and set it as static web hosting without dockerizing it, or I could dockerize it and deploy it in ECS and still as a static web page. In my opinion, hosting it in S3 would be way easier, but what benefits or under what circumstances, it is best to dockerize my angular app and deploy it in ECS?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it is totally fine to host your static site on S3, but think about day 2 operations... How would you deploy new changes to the site? back up the site? revert to a specific version? of course, you can do all of it with scripting around S3 but it will require some effort...  in my opinion building a container to serve static files is very simple and does not require more effort than creating the bucket, configuring it to serve static files, and add/create the required scripting/tooling to maintain and support the site. containers will win for me because of the ability to store and tag containers with specific versions(based on a specific commit) and better control over logs and debugging will win me. if it's a very low maintenance site go with a bucket otherwise I think it's worth containerizing it.